# 530 USer cannot log in when trying to access site folder via FTP

Tags: ftp, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, filezilla

I try to log in to my Windows 2012 server via FTP:

```
Command:    USER ftp_*****
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS **********
Response:   530 User cannot log in.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

The FTP is connected via port 22. Using FileZilla.

What I've checked:

- Port is open on the server
- I have entered the right username and password
- Checked Active and Passive, doesn't solve the problem
- I gave read write permission for that FTP site
- I opened the TCP port 22 in Windows firewall for outbound connections
- I've given the ftp user permission on the website folder (full permissions)

What else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Another FTP site was listening on the same port. I just stopped it and the other one worked.